# Is a constant literal an example of a built-in?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, language-design

My understanding is that in a programming language, *built-ins* are bindings that exist without the user having to make them. (Like `+` to its referent, for example.)

My understanding of a *constant literal* is that it is a variable whose name encodes its value. (Like `3`, or `{"Name": "Steve", "age": 47}` in JS.

Is a constant literal considered a type of built-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal is not a variable.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming).

I wouldn't consider a literal a "built-in", but I'm not familiar with a precise formal definition of "built-in".